# Angularjs factory: errors on passing $scope,$route,$http?

Tags: angularjs, jquery, requirejs

Why my factory below keep throwing an error when the `$scope, $route, $http` are present?

```
app.factory("factoryContacts",function($scope,$route,$http){

        return {
            getContacts: function(){
               return $http({
                    method: 'GET', 
                    url:'php/listContacts.php'
                }).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.contacts = response.data;

                 });
            }
        };
   });
```

can't I pass `$scope, $route, $http` into a factory?

I tested with this basic one and it gives me the same error,

```
app.provider('helloWorld', function($scope) { // note $scope is present
        // In the provider function, you cannot inject any
        // service or factory. This can only be done at the
        // "$get" method.

        this.name = 'Default';

        this.$get = function() {
            var name = this.name;
            return {
                sayHello: function() {
                    return "Hello, " + name + "! From Provider!!"
                }
            }
        };

        this.setName = function(name) {
            this.name = name;
        };
    });
```

What should I do?

the error,

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20factoryContacts ... <ng-view class="ng-scope">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can't I pass $scope, $route, $http into a factory?

**why not $scope**

You can't inject $scope into service/factory, its singleton and has *local scope*. But you can use `$rootScope`

To pass `$route` and  `$http` use injection and write like:

```
app.factory("factoryContacts",['$route','$http', function($route,$http){

        return {
            getContacts: function(){
               return $http({
                    method: 'GET', 
                    url:'php/listContacts.php'
                }).then(function(response) {
                    //....

                 });
            }
        };
   }]);
```