# Error: error:unpr Unknown Provider injected service in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, service

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, all of my other services work no problem. What i'm attempting to do is upload a photo. Originally the service part of the code was inside the controller, and i refactored it to be a service because I didnt want to write another whole set of code to upload again after editing a photo(This is what service is for right?)

controller:

```
app.controller('UploadCtrl', ['$scope', '$upload','UploadService',
function($scope, $upload,UploadService) {
    $scope.uploads = [];
    var photos = $scope.$parent.photos;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $scope.uploads[i] = {
            id: i+1,
            showLink: photos[i].showLink,
            showProg: false,
            progress: 0,
            photoUrl: photos[i].dataUrl
        }
    }
}
]);
```

factory:

```
app.factory('UploadService',['$upload', '$scope', function($upload,$scope){

$scope.onFileSelect = function($files, $_upload) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        var $file = $files[i];

        //set thumbnail
        $scope.dataUrl = null;
        if ($file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL($file)

            var loadFile = function(fileReader) {

                fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                    // console.log(e.target.result);
                    $_upload.dataUrl = e.target.result;
                    $_upload.showLink = false;
                    $_upload.showProg = true;
                }
            }(fileReader);
        }

$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: 'upload_picture',
            method: 'POST',
            file: $file,
            fileFormDataName: 'provider[photo_' + $_upload.id + ']'
        }).progress(function(event) {

            $_upload.progress = parseInt(100.0 * event.loaded / event.total);
            // console.log('percent: ' + $_upload.progress);
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // file is uploaded successfully
            // console.log("success")
            // console.log(data);
            $_upload.showProg = false;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error");
        });
    }
};

var UploadService = $scope.onFileSelect($files,$upload);
return UploadService;   
}]);
```

based off this:
https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Comment: You cannot inject $scope into a factory function.  Define a factory correctly (see Chandermani's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, a service cannot take dependency on scope, so you cannot inject $scope (can inject $rootScope). You cannot copy and paste code from your controller implementation and paste into service.
The factory service needs to create service object and then attach functions and return at last

```
app.factory('UploadService',['$upload', function($upload){
   var service = {};
   service.upload = $upload.upload({
      ...
   });
   return service;
}]);
```

Comment: thank you for your input, i have figured it out now!

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject $scope into a factory / service. You can use $rootScope, but you should probably be returning a promise from your factory.

Here is another similar question. [Angularjs factory: errors on passing $scope,$route,$http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829166/angularjs-factory-errors-on-passing-scope-route-http)

```
app.factory('UploadService',['$upload', '$q', function($upload, $q){

   var deferred = $q.defer();

   return{

       upload: function(uploadConfig){

           $upload.upload(uploadConfig)
               .success(function(data){
                   deferred.resolve(data);
               }).error(function(error){
                   deferred.reject(error);
               });

           return deferred.promise;

       }

   }

}]);
```